# Upperbound for difference between chromatic number $\chi(G)$ and list-chromatic number $\chi_L(G)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

As we all know, coloring is just special case of more general thing, list-coloring. And it leads to conclusion that

$$\chi_L(G) \ge \chi(G)$$

Well, it is pretty cool, but is there any upperbound on how big $\chi_L(G)$ can actually be? In comparison with $\chi(G)$, of course.

In other words, is there any general upper bound on difference between $\chi_L(G)$ and $\chi(G)$?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the answer is [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X95003506?via%3Dihub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gap between $\chi$ and $\chi_L$ can be arbitrarily large. A construction for seeing this is provided in a [survey paper](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/british2.pdf) by Alon. In summary, given a complete bipartite graph, then its chromatic number is clearly equal to $2$. However, for any $k \geq 2$, there are bipartite graphs whose list-chromatic number exceeds $k$.

There is a nice little article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) about this specific example as well.

There is a famous conjecture given independently by various researchers such as Vizing or Tucker.

**Conjecture:** Every graph $G$ satisfies $\chi_{L}'(G)=\chi'(G)$, where $\chi'$ denotes the chromatic number of the line graph of $G$ and $\chi_{L}'$ denotes the list-chromatic number of the line graph of $G$.

There are several other graph classes for which the equality $\chi=\chi_{L}$ is conjectured, such as the Claw-free graphs (the class of graphs that do not contain a $K_{1,3}$ as an induced subgraph). If we take a closer look at line graphs, then we quickly realize that they are claw-free, thus this conjecture comes more or less natural.

Noel, Reed and Wu provided a proof for the following result.

**Theorem:** Every simple graph $G$ with $|V(G)| \leq 2\chi(G)+1$ satisfies $\chi_{L}(G)=\chi(G)$.

The above was first conjectured by Ohba in 2002.

**References**

[1] Beineke, Lowell W., and Robin J. Wilson, eds. Topics in chromatic graph theory. Vol. 156. Cambridge University Press, 2015.

[2] J.A. Noel, B.A. Reed and H. Wu, A proof of a conjecture of Ohba, manuscript, (2012).